# How I change loaded files names in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3quU.jpg)

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvGsI.jpg)

I am trying to create a dropdown with all the files located in a specific path the problem is when I load the files the show in the dropdown with the full path as a name for it how I change this and just keep the file name show in the dropdown?
How can I fix it?

```
void loadedfiles()
{
    string[] myload = getfilesname();
}

string[] getfilesname()
{
    string folderPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, foldername);
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.txt");
    foreach (string file in filePaths)
    {
        mylist.Add(file);
        Debug.Log(file);
    }
    dropi.AddOptions(mylist);
    return filePaths;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youc can use [`Path.GetFileName(string path)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename) (or also [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(string path)`](https://learn.microsoft.comdotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension)) to get only the filename part from a given path string.

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.txt");
foreach (string file in filePaths)
{
    var onlyFileName = Path.GetFileName(file);

    mylist.Add(onlyFileName);
    Debug.Log(onlyFileName);
}
```

---

As alternative but maybe not the best/cleanest solution

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.txt");
foreach (string file in filePaths)
{
    // split the path into all parts on the seperators (/ or \)
    var pathParts = file.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

    // take only the last part which should be the filename
    var onlyFileName = pathParts[pathParts.Length - 1];

    mylist.Add(onlyFileName);
    Debug.Log(onlyFileName);
}
```

Comment: thank you ites work i really thank you i just removed the convert from it and its work perfectly thank you again